# Flipping Fractions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, fractions

[image]

I'm currently reading Differential Equations for Dummies, and this is what it says on pg 60.

I wasn't too sure whether "flipping fractions" still satisfy the equation, and I searched online (including this site), but it seems that most people say flipping fraction is not correct. At the same time, there does seem to be a specific method that allows you to "flip fractions" correctly. Could someone help me understand how? (i.e. how to get from the first eq shown to the second eq.)

Comment: You can get it the following way: $\frac{dv}{dx}(x)=-\frac{v(x)(v^2(x)+1)}{v^2(x)-1}\frac{1}{x}$. Then $dv=-\frac{v(x)(v^2(x)+1)}{v^2(x)-1}\frac{1}{x}dx$. From this you get that $\frac{v^2(x)-1}{v(x)(v^2(x)+1)}dv=-\frac{1}{x}dx$. And finally $\frac{1}{x}dx+\frac{v^2(x)-1}{v(x)(v^2(x)+1)}dv=0$.

Comment: Since we did some divisions or multiplications, just be mindful of possible solutions of the last equation for which $v$ takes the value $1$ or $-1$. They might not be solutions of the original equation. Or of constant solutions like $v(x)=0$, that would not be allowed in the last, but satisfy the first equation.

Comment: Yes, that's true—thank you for pointing that out! I was wondering though if there might be a more "direct"/shortcut way of figuring out when flipping fractions (As they are written) is allowed w/o going through intermediate steps

Answer (score 0):

The thing that justifies this is the chain rule.

An example occurring in first-year calculus can illustrate this. Suppose you know that
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac d{dx} \tan x = \sec^2 x = 1+\tan^2 x = 1+y^2.
$$
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = 1+y^2.
$$
$$
\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac 1 {1+y^2}.
$$
$$
\frac d{dy} \arctan y = \frac 1 {1+y^2}.
$$
So how is this the chain rule?
$$
x = \arctan y = \arctan(\tan x) \tag 1
$$
Differentiating both sides of $(1)$ yields
$$
1 = {} \overbrace{ \frac d{dx} \arctan y = \big(\arctan'y\big)\cdot \frac{dy}{dx} }^\text{chain rule}
$$
Therefore
$$
\frac 1 {dy/dx} = \arctan'y.
$$

(And then $dy/dx = \sec^2 x = 1+\tan^2 x = 1+y^2.$)